How to make a line plot in R summarizing age required to be enrolled in clinical studies
I am studying a database of clinical trials. Each row is a clinical trial and I have two columns minAge and maxAge representing the minimum and maximum age patients should be in order to be enrolled in that specific trial.
E.g.



minAge
maxAge




12
25


10
17


11
30



I would like, using R, to plot a line graph which has as x axis the range of ages (e.g. 5, 35) and, on the y axis, the number of studies that allows that particular age to be enrolled. In this example it should be (5,0) ; (6,0) ... (10,1) ; (11,2) ; (12,3) ; (13,3) ... (17,3) ; (18,2) ...
I can deal with the ggplot function,  but I have not come with an intelligent way to summarize the columns (they are about 400) to be passed to ggplot.
Could someone help me? Thanks.

sapply(5:35, function(i) sum(yourdata$minAge >= i & yourdata$maxAge <= i))

@qdread  that gives me a vector of 35 zeroes

If you want brevity and low dependency, this would work:
colSums(sapply(5:35, \(i) sapply(studies$minAge, \(min) i >= min) & sapply(studies$maxAge, \(max) i <= max)))

@Captain Hat Whoops, I just wrote the greater than and less than signs backward. Should be sapply(5:35, function(i) sum(yourdata$minAge <= i & yourdata$maxAge >= i))

Here's a tidyverse solution using dplyr and tidyr:
Load libraries and initialise data:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


studies <- 
  tribble(~ minAge, ~maxAge,
          12,       25,
          10,       17, 
          11,       30)

Add a column that numbers each study:
studies <- mutate(studies, study = row_number(),
                  .before = 1)
studies
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   study minAge maxAge
#>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     12     25
#> 2     2     10     17
#> 3     3     11     30

Reshape the data with pivot_longer() so that age-range extremes are all in one column:

studies <- 
  pivot_longer(studies,
             c(minAge, maxAge),
             names_pattern = "(.+)Age",
             names_to = "min_max",
             values_to = "age") |> 
  select(-min_max)

studies

#   study   age
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1    12
# 2     1    25
# 3     2    10
# 4     2    17
# 5     3    11
# 6     3    30


Covert the age column into a column that explicitly contains every year in the range described, using full_seq():

studies <- 
  group_by(studies, study) |> 
  reframe(age = full_seq(age, 1))

studies
#> # A tibble: 42 × 2
#>    study   age
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1    12
#>  2     1    13
#>  3     1    14
#>  4     1    15
#>  5     1    16
#>  6     1    17
#>  7     1    18
#>  8     1    19
#>  9     1    20
#> 10     1    21
#> # ℹ 32 more rows

For the number of times each unique value of age occurs (i.e. the number of studies)

studies <- 
  group_by(studies, age) |> 
  count()

studies
#> # A tibble: 21 × 2
#> # Groups:   age [21]
#>      age     n
#>    <dbl> <int>
#>  1    10     1
#>  2    11     2
#>  3    12     3
#>  4    13     3
#>  5    14     3
#>  6    15     3
#>  7    16     3
#>  8    17     3
#>  9    18     2
#> 10    19     2
#> # ℹ 11 more rows

Plot the data. I think a step plot is more appropriate than a line plot here because your eligibility 'jumps' when you increase in age.

ggplot(studies, aes(x = age, y = n)) +
  geom_step() +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "No. possible studies")


Created on 2024-11-06 with reprex v2.1.1

Here is a more concise way of doing the same thing using the cryptic apply function.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

studies <- 
  tribble(~ minAge, ~maxAge,
          12,       25,
          10,       17, 
          11,       30)

plot_data <- 
  apply(studies, 1, full_seq, 1) |>  # Turn each row into an integer sequence
  unlist() |>                        # unlist into single numeric vector
  as_tibble() |>                     # turn into a tibble
  count(.by = value) |>              # count occurnces of each age
  set_names("Age", "Studies")        # name appropriately

# And plot
# ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Age, y = Studies)) + 
#   geom_step()


Created on 2024-11-06 with reprex v2.1.1
